# How do I make certain tables searchable by google?

Tags: perl, search, seo

I'm using perl, and I want others to find certain issues on my site using google. How can I do that?

In wordpress (php) there is this option:

> I would like my blog to be visible to
>   everyone, including search engines
>   (like Google, Bing, Technorati) and
>   archivers

I would like to do the same using perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML content (Of course, you have to find a way to display your data in HTML - either static HTML pages or dyanmic content) *could* be crawled and archived by Google without any effort on your part (this happens all the time, and is probably how most people do it), but it could help if you submit a google sitemap. Here's a page with more about Google Sitemaps: http://www.google.com/sitemap.html

Also, search on google for "Google sitemap" to get more info ;)

Beware though: SEO (Search Engine Optimization) is not an exact science (despite what anyone tells you).

Answer (score 2):

1. Express the data in HTML (I'd use a combination of Template-Toolkit and DBIx::Class (assuming you mean a database table))
2. Expose it over HTTP (I'd tend towards Catalyst for this)
3. Link to it (or use a [sitemap xml](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184))

Comment: I did not understand, is there a kind of example?

Comment: Example of what, precisely? You have a very vague question (so you got a vague answer).

Comment: I think what the OP's asking for is a site-specific Google search feature. Not very clear though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: i would like to search for something saved on my database and find it on google, what is vague about it.. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @zeina: And where do you want to start the search from: Your own search form, google.com, or a site-specific google search?

Comment: Well, I want the user to go to google, type something and get my site as one of the results, if it matches the search for sure.
I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough, I'm trying to explain as possible.

Comment: Then yes. Just build a website (i.e. HTML with links). That's all. It doesn't matter what backend technology you use.

Answer (score 0):

What David Dorward said.

Google will not look into your database; you must create web pages containing all the information you want exposed and then point google to those pages by submitting a sitemap.